# A JavaFX canvas - based UI view component for representing data points in three dimensions

Tags: java, canvas, javafx

I have this pie chart. It encodes data points in three dimensions, which are encoded via

1. sector radius,
2. sector angle,
3. color intensity of the sector.

**How it looks like?**

(See [here](https://imgur.com/n9RkG2h).)

**Code**

**`com.github.coderodde.javafx.PieChart3D.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.javafx;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.ArcType;

/**
 * This class implements a pie chart that can communicate data points in three
 * dimensions:
 * <ol>
 * <li>the radius of a sector,</li>
 * <li>the angle of a sector,</li>
 * <li>color intensity of a sector.</li>
 * </ol>
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 18, 2023)
 * @since 1.6 (Dec 18, 2023)
 */
public final class PieChart3D extends Canvas {
    
    private static final Color DEFAULT_BOX_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
    private static final Color DEFAULT_CHART_BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
    private static final Color DEFAULT_ORIGINAL_INTENSITY_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
    
    private Color boxColor               = DEFAULT_BOX_COLOR;
    private Color chartBackgroundColor   = DEFAULT_CHART_BACKGROUND_COLOR;
    private Color originalIntensityColor = DEFAULT_ORIGINAL_INTENSITY_COLOR;
    private double angleOffset           = 0.0;
    
    private final List<PieChart3DEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public PieChart3D(double dimension) {
        checkDimension(dimension);
        super.setWidth(dimension);
        super.setHeight(dimension);
    }
    
    public Color getBoxBackgroundColor() {
        return boxColor;
    }

    public Color getChartBackgroundColor() {
        return chartBackgroundColor;
    }

    public Color getOriginalIntensityColor() {
        return originalIntensityColor;
    }
    
    public double getAngleOffset() {
        return angleOffset;
    }

    public void setBoxBackgroundColor(Color boxColor) {
        this.boxColor = 
                Objects.requireNonNull(boxColor, "The input color is null.");
    }

    public void setChartBackgroundColor(Color chartBackgroundColor) {
        this.chartBackgroundColor = 
                Objects.requireNonNull(
                        chartBackgroundColor, 
                        "The input color is null.");
    }

    public void setOriginalIntensityColor(Color originalIntensityColor) {
        this.originalIntensityColor =
                Objects.requireNonNull(
                        originalIntensityColor,
                        "The input color is null.");
    }
    
    public void setAngleOffset(double angleOffset) {
        checkAngleOffset(angleOffset);
        angleOffset %= 360.0;
        
        if (angleOffset < 0.0) {
            angleOffset += 360.0;
        }
        
        this.angleOffset = angleOffset;
    }
    
    public PieChart3DEntry get(int index) {
        return entries.get(index);
    }
    
    public void set(int index, PieChart3DEntry entry) {
        entries.set(index, Objects.requireNonNull(entry, "The entry is null."));
    }
    
    public int size() {
        return entries.size();
    }
    
    public void add(PieChart3DEntry entry) {
        entries.add(Objects.requireNonNull(entry, "The entry is null."));
    }
    
    public void add(int index, PieChart3DEntry entry) {
        entries.add(index, Objects.requireNonNull(entry, "The entry is null."));
    }
    
    public void remove(int index) {
        entries.remove(index);
    }
    
    public void draw() {
        GraphicsContext gc = getGraphicsContext2D();
        drawBoundingBox(gc);
        drawEntirePieChart(gc);
        
        if (!entries.isEmpty()) {
            // Once here, we have entries to draw:
            drawChart(gc);
        }
    }
    
    private void drawBoundingBox(GraphicsContext gc) {
        gc.setFill(getBoxBackgroundColor());
        gc.fillRect(0.0,
                    0.0,
                    getWidth(), 
                    getHeight());
    }
    
    private void drawEntirePieChart(GraphicsContext gc) {
        gc.setFill(getChartBackgroundColor());
        gc.fillOval(0.0,
                    0.0,
                    getHeight(),
                    getWidth());       
    }
    
    private void drawChart(GraphicsContext gc) {
        double sumOfRelativeAngles        = computeSumOfRelativeAngles();
        double maximumRadiusValue         = getMaximumRadiusValue();
        double maximumColorIntensityValue = getMaximumColorIntensity();
        double startAngle                 = 90.0 - angleOffset;
        
        for (PieChart3DEntry entry : entries) {
            
            double actualAngle = 360.0 * entry.getSectorAngleValue()
                                       / sumOfRelativeAngles;
            
            double actualRadius =
                    (getHeight() / 2.0) * (entry.getSectorRadiusValue() 
                                        / maximumRadiusValue);
                                        
            Color actualColor = 
                    obtainColor(entry.getSectorColorIntensityValue() / 
                                maximumColorIntensityValue);
            
            double sectorStartAngle = startAngle - actualAngle;
            
            startAngle -= actualAngle;
            
            drawSector(gc,
                       sectorStartAngle,
                       actualAngle,
                       actualRadius,
                       actualColor);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Draws a single sector.
     * 
     * @param gc           the graphics context.
     * @param startAngle   the start angle.
     * @param angle     the end angle.
     * @param actualRadius the radius of the sector.
     * @param color        the color of the sector.
     */
    private void drawSector(GraphicsContext gc, 
                            double startAngle,
                            double angle,
                            double actualRadius,
                            Color color) {
        
        double canvasDimension = getHeight();
        double centerX = canvasDimension / 2.0;
        double centerY = canvasDimension / 2.0;
        
        gc.setFill(color);
        gc.fillArc(centerX - actualRadius, 
                   centerY - actualRadius,
                   2.0 * actualRadius,
                   2.0 * actualRadius,
                   startAngle,
                   angle,
                   ArcType.ROUND);
    }
    
    private double computeSumOfRelativeAngles() {
        double angleSum = 0.0;
        
        for (PieChart3DEntry entry : entries) {
            angleSum += entry.getSectorAngleValue();
        }
        
        return angleSum;
    }
    
    private static void checkDimension(double dimension) {
        checkIsNotNaN(dimension, "The dimension is NaN.");
        checkIsNotInfinite(dimension,
                           "The dimention is infinite in absolute value.");
        
        if (dimension <= 0.0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The dimension is non-positive.");
        }
    }
    
    private static void checkAngleOffset(double angleOffset) {
        checkIsNotNaN(angleOffset, "The angle offset is NaN.");
        checkIsNotInfinite(angleOffset,
                           "The angle offset is infinite in absolute value.");
    }
    
    private static void checkIsNotNaN(double value, String exceptionMessage) {
        if (Double.isNaN(value)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(exceptionMessage);
        }
    }
    
    private static void checkIsNotInfinite(double value, 
                                           String exceptionMessage) {
        if (Double.isInfinite(value)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(exceptionMessage);
        }
    }
    
    private double getMaximumRadiusValue() {
        Optional<PieChart3DEntry> optional = 
                entries.stream().max((e1, e2) -> {
            return Double.compare(e1.getSectorRadiusValue(), 
                                  e2.getSectorRadiusValue()); 
        });
        
        if (optional.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No entries in this chart.");
        }
        
        return optional.get().getSectorRadiusValue();
    }
    
    private double getMaximumColorIntensity() {
        Optional<PieChart3DEntry> optional = 
                entries.stream().max((e1, e2) -> {
                    return Double.compare(e1.getSectorColorIntensityValue(), 
                                          e2.getSectorColorIntensityValue());
                });
        
        if (optional.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No entries in this chart.");
        }
        
        return optional.get().getSectorColorIntensityValue();
    }
    
    private double getSumOfEntrySectorAngles() {
        double sum = 0.0;
        
        for (PieChart3DEntry entry : entries) {
            sum += entry.getSectorAngleValue();
        }
        
        return sum;
    }
    
    private double normalizeSectorAngle(PieChart3DEntry entry) {
        return 360.0 * 
                (entry.getSectorAngleValue() / 
                 getSumOfEntrySectorAngles());
    }
    
    private Color obtainColor(double intensity) {
        double r = originalIntensityColor.getRed();
        double g = originalIntensityColor.getGreen();
        double b = originalIntensityColor.getBlue();
        
        r += (1.0 - r) * (1.0 - intensity);
        g += (1.0 - g) * (1.0 - intensity);
        b += (1.0 - b) * (1.0 - intensity);
        
        return new Color(r, g, b, 1.0);
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.javafx.PieChart3DEntry.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.javafx;

/**
 * This class implements the pie chart entry.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 18, 2023)
 * @since 1.6 (Dec 18, 2023)
 */
public final class PieChart3DEntry {
    
    /**
     * Holds the sector radius of this entry.
     */
    private double sectorRadiusValue;
    
    /**
     * Holds the sector angle of this entry.
     */
    private double sectorAngleValue;
    
    /**
     * Holds the sector color intensity of this entry.
     */
    private double sectorColorIntensityValue;
    
    public double getSectorRadiusValue() {
        return sectorRadiusValue;
    }

    public double getSectorAngleValue() {
        return sectorAngleValue;
    }

    public double getSectorColorIntensityValue() {
        return sectorColorIntensityValue;
    }

    public void setSectorRadiusValue(double sectorRadiusValue) {
        checkValue(sectorRadiusValue);
        this.sectorRadiusValue = sectorRadiusValue;
    }

    public void setSectorAngleValue(double sectorAngleValue) {
        checkValue(sectorAngleValue);
        this.sectorAngleValue = sectorAngleValue;
    }

    public void setSectorColorIntensityValue(double sectorColorIntensityValue) {
        checkValue(sectorColorIntensityValue);
        this.sectorColorIntensityValue = sectorColorIntensityValue;
    }
    
    public PieChart3DEntry withSectorRadiusValue(double sectorRadiusValue) {
        setSectorRadiusValue(sectorRadiusValue);
        return this;
    }
    
    public PieChart3DEntry withSectorAngleValue(double sectorAngleValue) {
        setSectorAngleValue(sectorAngleValue);
        return this;
    }
    
    public PieChart3DEntry withSectorColorIntensityValue(
            double sectorColorIntensityValue) {
        setSectorColorIntensityValue(sectorColorIntensityValue);
        return this;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[sectorRadiusValue = " 
                + sectorRadiusValue
                + ", sectorAngleValue = " 
                + sectorAngleValue 
                + ", sectorColorIntensityValue = "
                + sectorColorIntensityValue
                + "]";
    }

    private static void checkValue(double value) {
        if (Double.isNaN(value)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input value is NaN.");
        }
        
        if (Double.isInfinite(value)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input value is infinite.");
        }
        
        if (value < 0.0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input value is negative.");
        }
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.javafx.PieChart3DDemo.java:`**

```
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;
 
public class PieChart3DDemo extends Application {
    
    private static final double DIMENSION = 500.0;
    private static final double CANVAS_DIMENSION = 400.0;
    private static final int MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_SECTORS = 20;
    private static final double MAXIMUM_VALUE = 200.0;
    private static final double FULL_ANGLE = 360.0;
    private static final Color CHART_BACKGROUND_COLOR = new Color(0.9, 
                                                                  0.9,
                                                                  0.9,
                                                                  1.0);
    private static final DemoTask DEMO_TASK = new DemoTask();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime.getRuntime()
               .addShutdownHook(
                       new Thread(() -> {
                           DEMO_TASK.stop();
                       }));
        
        launch(args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("PieChart3D demo");
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        
        primaryStage.setScene(
                new Scene(root, 
                          DIMENSION,
                          DIMENSION));
        
        DEMO_TASK.setRoot(root);
        DEMO_TASK.setStage(primaryStage);
        
        new Thread(DEMO_TASK).start();
        
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    private static Color getRandomColor(Random random) {
        return new Color(random.nextDouble(),
                         random.nextDouble(),
                         random.nextDouble(),
                         1.0);
    }
    
    private static int getRandomNumberOfSectors(Random random) {
        return random.nextInt(MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_SECTORS + 1);
    }
    
    private static double getRandomValue(Random random) {
        return MAXIMUM_VALUE * random.nextDouble();
    }
    
    private static double getRandomAngleOffset(Random random) {
        return FULL_ANGLE * random.nextDouble();
    }
    
    static PieChart3D getRandomChart(Random random) {
        double angleOffset = getRandomAngleOffset(random);
        int numberOfSectors = getRandomNumberOfSectors(random);
        
        PieChart3D chart = new PieChart3D(CANVAS_DIMENSION);
        
        chart.setChartBackgroundColor(CHART_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        chart.setAngleOffset(angleOffset);
        chart.setOriginalIntensityColor(getRandomColor(random));
        
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSectors; i++) {
            PieChart3DEntry entry = 
                    new PieChart3DEntry()
                        .withSectorAngleValue(getRandomValue(random))
                        .withSectorColorIntensityValue(getRandomValue(random))
                        .withSectorRadiusValue(getRandomValue(random));
            
            chart.add(entry);
        }
        
        return chart;
    }
}

final class DemoTask extends Task<Void> {

    private static final long SLEEP_DURATION_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1L;
    private static final int FRAMES_PER_CHART = 2_000;
    
    private volatile boolean doRun = true;
    private final Random random = new Random();
    private StackPane root;
    private Stage stage;
    
    void stop() {
        doRun = false;
    }
    
    void setRoot(StackPane root) {
        this.root = root;
    }
    
    void setStage(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent t) {
                System.out.println("Exiting...");
                Platform.exit();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        
        int iterations = 0;
                
        while (doRun) {
            PieChart3D chart = PieChart3DDemo.getRandomChart(random);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < FRAMES_PER_CHART; i++) {

                Platform.runLater(() -> {    
                    root.getChildren().clear();
                    root.getChildren().add(chart);
                    
                    chart.setAngleOffset(chart.getAngleOffset() + 0.1);
                    chart.draw();
                });
                
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(SLEEP_DURATION_IN_MILLISECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
            }
            
            System.out.println("Iterated: " + ++iterations);
        }
        
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Critique request**

As always, I would like to hear any comment about improving the code.

Comment: @Mast Added a link to imgur.

Comment: Better, thanks. That should work for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small issue, I don't think `private static final DemoTask DEMO_TASK = new DemoTask();` needs `static`.

My other issue is with `DemoTask`  extending `Task<Void>`. Most time I see `Thread.sleep(SLEEP_DURATION_IN_MILLISECONDS);` in a JavaFX app, I think something is wrong. In your case, `getRandomChart(random)` does not appear to do a large amount of work. I think you should implement this using `TimeLine`. The way your `Task` is designed goes against how it was designed to be used. You should not be dependent on a boolean to stop and start a `Task`. Moreover, you should not try to stop a `Task` to begin with. `Task` should do some work and return some state they will allow you to get a value, update the GUI, or move forward.